# black and white screen with lines on PC monitor

Tags: motherboard, gpu, heatsink

from last 2 weeks my computer was booting almost after 30 seconds. Before 3 months ago, my computer hardware assistant had removed graphics card because of heating problem(as he said).

Before 2 days ago when i was working on PC, approximately after 20 minutes it started showing the same screen. I thought that it might be monitor problem and then i started connecting to PC with the laptop via homegroup and i was not able to connect because it was not functioning. Now last 2 days i am not able to start PC because its not booting. Any specific reason.

I have following hardware

```
AMD altlon x2 (6400)
4 GB RAM
500 + 500 GB Harddisk
Asus M3N-78EM motherboard
```

Motherboard has nvidia 8300 In-built graphics card and Before 3 months i removed nvidia 8400 GS. I used to run both in hybrid SLI.

I am using windows 7 home basic genuine version + Kaspersky Internet Security 2012 and i update both thing regularly.

[This is my dropbox url to the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qmi270cgiodl2y/20072012.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all devices one a a time (or remove all and add them back one at a time) until you see which module it is / isn't faulting.

When you say it doesn't boot, does this mean the fans stop as well or you just get nothing on screen?

Comment: fans are running but blank screen, the beep sound is not coming when its start

Comment: This means the PSU and CPU are *likely* to be OK. Are you using your onboard graphic card now? I had a very similar issue to what you're describing, taking out the battery on the motherboard for literally 2 minutes and then putting it back allowed it to boot up.

Comment: I am not using graphics card now. Means external one. Motherboard has inbuilt graphics card. I will try and lets see what happens.!

Comment: wow..! got the time in this weekend and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you have a hardware problem. You'd better take it to a computer service center.

One simple way to confirm is to just load up a Linux live CD (or USB). Get the latest version of Ubuntu and see if it boots up (do NOT install Linux!). If it does, then good - you do not appear to have a hardware problem. Otherwise, you might want to get your warranty card ready.